# regex or way to get urls for images only

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to download images from the following page http://wordpandit.com/learning-bin/visual-vocabulary/page/2/
I downloaded it using urllib and have parsed using BeautifulSoup. It contains many urls, I want only those urls that end with .jpg, they also have rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" tag.
How to do this using Beautifulsoup? 
Eg of the link http://wordpandit.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Obliterate.jpg

```
#http://wordpandit.com/learning-bin/visual-vocabulary/page/2/
import urllib
import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
baseurl='http://wordpandit.com/learning-bin/visual-vocabulary/page/'
count=2


for count in range(1,2):
    url=baseurl+count+'/'
    soup1=BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))#read will not be needed
    #find all links to imgs
    atag=soup.findAll(rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]")
    for tag in atag:
        soup2=BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(tag)
        imgurl=soup2.find(href).value
        urllib2.urlopen(imgurl)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a lot of unnecessary things. Maybe you will use them later, but something like assigning `count` as `2` and then using it as a counter in a `for range` loop is just pointless. Here is the code that will do what you want:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
baseurl='http://wordpandit.com/learning-bin/visual-vocabulary/page/'

for count in range(1,2):
    url = baseurl + str(count) + "/"
    html_page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
    atag = soup.findAll(rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]", href = True)
    for tag in atag:
        if tag['href'].endswith(".jpg"):
            imgurl = tag['href']
            img = urllib2.urlopen("http://wordpandit.com" + imgurl)
            with open(imgurl.split("/")[-1], "wb") as local_file:
                local_file.write(img.read())
```

Comment: Need a `.read()` on that `html_page` and might be wise to add an `href=True` to your `findAll` (nb: would/should be `find_all` if using bs4) query

Comment: @JonClements, why do I need to `read()` the `html_page`? Will it be faster or just more correct? (it works without it)

Comment: Because until you read it, there's no data - it's just a connection object.... try printing your `soup` and you'll find it's nothing more than `str(html_page)`

Comment: @JonClements, if I print `soup` it gives me all the HTML code. I'm using Python 2.7.5, Urllib2 .7, BeautifulSoup 4.3.1 (both on Linux and Windows)

Comment: Okay - I take that back... in the "old" days, you had to provide soup with a string... Looks like it caters for that gotcha now :) Sorry about that ;)

Comment: Anyway might I suggest looking at http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve for the second part of your code (for the downloading) and you can use the following to simplify your code greatly: `img_urls = ['http://wordpandit.com' + el['href'] for el in soup.find_all(rel='prettyPhoto[gallery]', href=re.compile('\.jpg$'))]` and then `for img_url in img_urls`

Comment: @JonClements,@ton1c,thanks a lot for the answer,i am new to python,beautifulsoup andregex. your answers have helped a lot